# How to make "select option" select option for quantity using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select option for a quantity that I want to make it hide and show depending on the value. Quantities are from 1 to 4, when the option value is "more" the `select` element will hide then the `input name="quantity-input"` will show up so you can type manually quantity you like from 1 to 50.

```
<input type="number" name="quantity-input" id="qty-input" hidden>

<select name="quantity-select" id="qty-select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="more">more</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm using jquery to make selectors easier. let me know at the comment section if something doesn't work as you want.

```js
$('.QuantSelect_').change(function(){
  const QuantSelect_ = $(this);
  const QuanMoreIn_ = QuantSelect_.parent().find('.QuanMoreIn_').eq(0);
  const switchInput = QuantSelect_.parent().find('.switchInput_').eq(0);

  let selected_ = QuantSelect_.val();
  if( selected_ === 'more' ){
    QuantSelect_.hide();
    QuanMoreIn_.show().focus();

    switchInput.show().click(function(){
      QuantSelect_.toggle(); QuanMoreIn_.toggle();
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="QuanForm">
  <input class="QuanMoreIn_" type="number" name="quantity-input" placeholder="Enter the specific Number" style="display:none;" />

  <select class="QuantSelect_" name="quantity-select">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="more">more</option>
  </select>
  <button class="switchInput_" style="display:none;">switch</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! but after the input shows up how can the cursor directly be inside the input? so on a smartphone after the input shows up the keyboard also will show up. Thanks !!

Comment: yah good idea. i already change it. check the revision

Comment: Okay (: . i change the code a bit and adding switch input button. its more stable.

Answer (score 0):

You need an event-listener on select field which will mark the field hidden/disabled when More option is selected and make your input field visible.

```
document.getElementById('qty-select').addEventListener('change', event => {
  const currentValue = event.currentTarget.value;

  if (currentValue == 'more') {
    event.currentTarget.setAttribute('disabled', true);

    document.getElementById('qty-input').removeAttribute('hidden');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update html like below.

```
    <input type="number" name="quantity-input" id="qty-input" hidden min="1" max="50">

    <select name="quantity-select" id="qty-select" onclick="hideMe();">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="more">more</option>
    </select>
```

And add javascript function.

```
function hideMe() {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("qty-select");
    if(selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value == "more") {
        document.getElementById("qty-select").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("qty-input").removeAttribute('hidden');
    }
}
```